# '1004' Unable to get the Insert property of the Picture Class

Tags: excel, vba

I unfortunately do not have the new excel with the image formula so am trying to work on VBA but new to it and I keep getting an error.

I've saved all of my images in my one drive folder and now am trying to pull them into excel however I keep getting this error - `'1004'  Unable to get the Insert property of the Picture Class`.

I have tried different versions and when I have manually typed in the address it works but when I have the variable in the link and switching between `png` and `jpg` photos it doesn't work anymore.

I would really appreciate any advice.

```
Sub URLPhotoInsert()
    Dim cRange As Range
    Dim cItem As Range
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fExists As String
    Set cRange = Selection
    Set cItem = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    Image_Location = "https:/Images/...."
    Image_Format1 = ".png"
    Image_Format2 = ".jpg"
    For i = 1 To cRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To cRange.Columns.Count
            fName = "Image_Location +  cRange.Cells(i, j)+ Image_Format1"
            fExists = Dir(fName)
            If fExists = "" Then
                Set Image = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CStr(Image_Location + cRange.Cells(i, j) + Image_Format2))
            Else
                Set Image = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(CStr(Image_Location + cRange.Cells(i, j) + Image_Format1))
            End If
            Image.ShapeRange.Height = cItem.Height
            Image.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            Image.Left = cItem.Cells(i, j).Left
            Image.Top = cItem.Cells(i, j).Top
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I was hoping to be able to insert images that I have saved in my one drive next to the column of styles that I saved.

Answer (score 1):

```
fName = "Image_Location +  cRange.Cells(i, j)+ Image_Format1"
```

Anything within quotes is considered as 1 string. When you are passing the file name as `"Image_Location +  cRange.Cells(i, j)+ Image_Format1"`, it is considering this text as path which is not right.

What you want is to create 1 string using multiple variables. For example: `Image_Location`, `Image_Format1`, the value from `cRange.Cells(i, j)`.

Remove the double quotes and try again. Also use `&` and not `+` for String concatenation. Something like this

```
fName = Image_Location &  cRange.Cells(i, j).Value2 & Image_Format1
```

Also change the line

```
CStr(Image_Location + cRange.Cells(i, j) + Image_Format1)
```

to

```
Image_Location & cRange.Cells(i, j).Value2 & Image_Format1
```

Similarly for the other. Use `&`.

And if you are still getting an error then put a breakpoint and check what is the value of the image path.

The other thing that I noticed is that with the line

```
If fExists = "" Then
```

You are checking if `fName` exists or not and if it doesn't exists then you are assuming that the file with extension `.jpg` will exist and you are using that as the image path. If this file doesn't exists then this will also give you the same error.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It looks like by changing to fName = "Image_Location & cRange.Cells(i, j).Value & Image_Format1" the filepath check now works, however I still get the same error at the Set Image = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Image_Location & cRange.Cells(i, j) & Image_Format2) line

Comment: Like I mentioned, put a break point and check what is the value of `(Image_Location & cRange.Cells(i, j) & Image_Format2)`

Comment: It tells me "object required" when it goes to : ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Image_Location & cName.Value & Image_Format2).Select.  But I'm not quite sure what that means?

Comment: Yes put a breakpoint on that line. If you do nto know what breakpoitns are then see [THIS](https://youtu.be/1ZLuco1-klw)

Comment: Sorry I watched the video but still not sure what the solution is

Comment: You need to learn how to put a breakpoint and then run the code.